# jQuery.ajax converter not called

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

I'm having trouble with jQuery.ajax converters - I can't get my converter to be called.

I've got this jQuery AJAX code (simplified for the question) :

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://myurl/myservice",
    dataType: "JSONP",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { /* do stuff */ },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* do stuff */ },
    timeout: 5000,
    converters: { "JSONP": myConversionFunction }
});
```

When I use this code, the converter function *myConversionFunction* isn't being called. I want to use the converter to convert dates in the response as show in other SO questions but just can't get it firing.

Using fiddler I've checked the response and it is JSONP, with content type "application/x-javascript".

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can't overwrite jQuery's default converters like `json`. Introduce your own converter instead (and include `text` in your specifier, as in this case it's a conversion from text to your output):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://myurl/myservice",
    dataType: "jsonp myConversion",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { /* do stuff */ },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* do stuff */ },
    timeout: 5000,
    converters: {
        "text myConversion": function(value) {
            console.log("pre-processing...");
            /* do stuff */
            return value;
        }
    }
});
```

​

Comment: (Removed previous comment - I misread the solution). Thanks Julian, you've set me on the right track. Adding my own conversion is ensuring I get the function call.

Comment: I'm trying the above solution and it's not working for me. I want to pre-process something that returns HTML and treat it as JSONP. I even changed "text myConversion" to "* myConversion". Just point URL to anything that returns HTML (www.google.com, for instance). I get a syntax error in IE/Chrome and it fails silently in FF.

Comment: JSONP expects that the raw returned content to be valid JavaScript: it is in fact a `<script>` call to the given location. It is therefore not possible to use JSONP to transport arbitrary data such as HTML pages without additional processing on the server side (wrapping in a function call). Attempts to do so will usually throw a syntax error when the browser tries to interpret the received data as JavaScript. Also, you cannot access the transmitted data itself due to the browser's cross domain policies.

Comment: Understood. I kind of thought that might be the case. So I guess to process cross-domain HTML via Ajax, I would have to make a server on my domain to call that calls the remote domain in the background and pre-processes the HTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use code like this to manage the 'd' data of asp.net:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    converters:
        {
            "json jsonp": function(msg)
            {
                return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
            }
        },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        var errorMessage = "Ajax error: " + this.url + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown + " : " + xhr.statusText +
                " : " + xhr.status;
        if (xhr.status != "0" || errorThrown != "abort")
        {
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
    }
});
```

perhaps you need to make it lower case like:

```
converters:
    {
        "json jsonp": function(msg)
        {
            return yourfunction(msg);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no luck. I've tried changing the data type to "jsonp" and then tried all sorts of converter key matches such as "json jsonp", "json", "jsonp" but the function isn't being called.

Comment: Have you tried putting the contentType in? `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: I'm not doing jsonp, but you can override json like this:

Comment: @ChristopherDavies: please fix